# Change text depending on the time of day and on which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display different text 'set' depending on which button I click, and rotate messages in this 'set' depending on what time it is.
This is what I've got:

```
var date = new Date;
var hh = date.getHours();
var mm = date.getMinutes();

if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}

var t = hh+":"+mm;

    var themessage;
function TimeF() {
    if (check == "alt") {
    if (t >= "08:00" && t <= "09:00"){
      themessage = "A";
    }
    else if(t >= "09:05" && t <= "10:05"){
      themessage = 2;
    }
    }

    else if (check == "NoPack") {
    if (t >= "08:00" && t <= "09:14"){
      themessage = "NP";
    }
    else if(t >= "09:19" && t <= "10:33"){
      themessage = 2;
    }
    }
        else if (check == "pack") {
            if (t >= "08:00" && t <= "09:14") {
            themessage = "pack";
    }
    }

  else if (n == 3) {
    if (t >= "08:00" && t <= "09:14"){
      themessage = "n=3";
    }
    else if(t >= "09:19" && t <= "10:33"){
      themessage = 2;
  }
  }
  else {
   if (t >= "08:00" && t <= "09:19") {
       themessage = "Else";
    }
    else if (t >= "09:21" && t<= "10:43"){
        themessage =2;
    }
  } 
 $('.Test').append(themessage);
}
```

Also I have button code:

```
var reg = document.getElementById("Reg");
var pack = document.getElementById("Pack");
var nopack = document.getElementById("NoPack");
var alt = document.getElementById("Alt");
var sch = document.getElementById("Sch");
var check;
var update;


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Pack").click(function () {
    $("#Sch").html("pack");
    check = "pack";
});
$("#Reg").click(function () {
    $("#Sch").html("Reg");
    check = "reg";
});
$("#NoPack").click(function () {
    $("#Sch").html("NoPack");
    check = "NoPack";
});
    $("#Alt").click(function () {
    $("#Sch").html("Alternate");
    check = "alt";
});
})
```

The problem is - when I press any button, the code shows the text for 'esle', and not what I supposed to be assigned to that button.
P.S I have jquery refference and I am loading this function TimeF in body.
If you want, I could make a quick CodePen with this.
P.S.S n==3 in my code - is checking if it is Wednesday.

Comment: Are you running TimeF after button click? Because the 'check' var only gets set after you click a button, TimeF will need to run after that variable is set.

Comment: I tried to make it update after I click the button. I.E var update; update = setTimeout(TimeF, 3000); (but it in the button code). And all it did is added another 'Else' message. (ElseElse - output)

Comment: I don't think you can do time comparison by string value. You will need to compare integers for hour and mins

Comment: No, it actually works fine. @Liquidchrome

Comment: I mean if is shows the message "else", then the time works fine. what doen't work though - is that it still shows "else" after I press the button.

Comment: it seems to work fine for me... it just doesn't show anything for me because 'themessage' never gets set (it's 12:20pm here so mine doesn't match the t >= "08:00" && t <= "09:19"). I tried adding my own button code to match yours in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wyoysvee/